# iPhone mailer shows quicklook of image when tapped

Tags: html, css, iphone, image, email

We embed images into our emails with content ID ("...src="cid:...). When we do that, as opposed to referencing remote images (src="https://....), the iPhone mail app shows a quicklook of those images when the users taps on them.

This would be fine, only it also does this when the image is inside an A tag - and then opens the URL (in the browser) **and** opens the quicklook. So when you return to the mail app, the quicklook is standing there - which is weird...

Any ideas how to format the img (some CSS?) to tell the iPhone to **not** open a Quicklook if it is tapped would by highly appreciated.

I tried changing from cid to a remote URL for the image - then the iPhone mailer does not display the Quicklook - but we need to embed the image via cid...

Answer (score 0):

I tried a workaround with using `<picture>` instead of `<img>` like this:

So instead of:

`<a href="..."><img src="cid:somecontentid"></a>`

use:

`<a href="..."><picture><source media="all" srcset="cid:somecontentid"><img src="#"></picture></a>`

If you wrap the image in a picture tag, the Apple Mail app does *not* show Quicklook when tapping the image.

But unfortunately it turned out that this does NOT work in Outlook :(

Outlook will not display this at all...